# How do I print out the occurences of each element in an area specified by a bounding box of a 2d matrix?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, frequency-distribution

```
void searchValidEntries(int arr[101][101], int XL, int YL, int XH, int YH){
  int sizeX = (XL - XH) + 1;
  int sizeY = (YH - YL) + 1;


  for (int i = XH; i < XH + sizeX; i++  ){
    for (int j = YL; j < YL + sizeY; j++){
      
      cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';

    }
  }

}
```

In the above code, I'm looping through a bounding box in a 2d array.
The coordinates of the array to be assigned a bounding box and the array itself are included as parameters in a function : `int arr[101][101], int XL, int YL, int XH, int YH`

The commented code `cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';` prints out the elements in the designated bounding box and I've run it so I know it actually prints out.

However, I want to get the frequency of each element in the bounding box, with the exception of 0, to be printed out.

I'm assuming that the required code will go in the for loop but I have no idea to start as I'm now learning all the semantics of C++.

I'm expecting an output of something like:

```
5 --> 3
83 --> 2
23 --> 9
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. I suggest using a vector< pair< int, int >>.

Each element of this vector holds two things:
1- a value that has been visited
2- the occurrence of this value
I've added some comments to my code to clarify this method.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

void searchValidEntries(int arr[101][101], int XL, int YL, int XH, int YH) {

    vector<pair<int, int>> holder_vec; 

    int sizeX = (XL - XH) + 1;
    int sizeY = (YH - YL) + 1;


    for (int i = XH; i < XH + sizeX; i++) {
        for (int j = YL; j < YL + sizeY; j++) {

            bool thisElementIsNew = true; // By default, it's the first occurence of this element.
            for (auto& it : holder_vec) { // Iterate the vector of previously considered elements and chekc this target value.

                if (it.first == arr[i][j]) {
                    it.second++; // Increase the occurence of this element by one.
                    thisElementIsNew = false; // This value has been previously visited.
                    break; // Stop iterating vector
                }               
            }

            if (thisElementIsNew) { // Add a new pair to holder_vec;
                const pair<int, int> newPair(arr[i][j], 1); // newPair.first = The value of this element.   // newPair.second = the occurence of this value.
                holder_vec.push_back(newPair);  
            }

        }
    }

    // Print result:
    for (const auto& it : holder_vec) {
        cout << it.first << " ---> " << it.second << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate over container if you use, for instance, map.
Something like this:
      map<int, int> nmap;  // number,count
      std::pair<std::map<int, int>::iterator, bool> ret;
      for (int i = XL; i < XL + sizeX; i++) {
          for (int j = YL; j < YL + sizeY; j++) {
              if (arr[i][j] > 0) {
                  ret = nmap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(arr[i][j], 1));
                  if (ret.second == false) 
                     ret.first->second++;
             }
       }
  }
  for (auto i : nmap)
    cout << i.first << " : " << i.second << endl;